# Why use underscores for parameters in Elixir, rather than no parameters at all?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I understand that Elixir uses underscores as parameters when they need to ignore those arguments. My question is, why have them at all?

```
def photos(_,_,_) do
    {:ok, Instagram.Posts.list_photos}
end

def photo(_, %{id: id}, _) do
    {:ok, Instagram.Posts.get_photo!(id)}
end
```

In this example here I have written a method (from a tutorial) that accepts three arguments, now none of them are used hence the underscores but why not have empty parentheses? In the second example I have used the Id argument but not the others, so why do I still need the underscores?

Comment: Look into pattern matching. Short answer: _ is used to ignore arguments on pattern match which allows invoking different function body depending on how they are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to let the system know that you know the variable is there but you will not use it. If you don't start the name with an underscore and not use the variable you will get a compile time warning, variable not being used.

For example you're dividing one number by another you can't divide by 0. So your code will look like this:

```
divide(_A, 0) -> "can't do";

divide(A, B) -> A/B.
```

We use the same function but it uses pattern matching to filter out the 0. As you will not be using the first number you name it with an underscore to tell the compiler to ignore that fact.

Comment: That builds on the other answer, that helps. So what your saying is that i want 2 divide functions, one will take a single number and divide by that and what ever is in the function. The second varient will take two params and divide one by the other. This way depending on what the function does is based on the params that it is passed. So the underscore signifies that its still the same function "foo" for example but it works differently based on the params

Comment: Exactly, it's called function overloading in Erlang.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. If we're not using them at all, we can set the function without parameters:

```
def f() do
  # Do something...
end
```

However, Elixir and its parent, Erlang, identify functions together with their arity; and if we use some or all of the parameters in the same function some of the time, we need a way to identify which parameters are set and how.

In Elixir, this:

```
def f(a) do
  # ...
end
```

Is a *different function* than:

```
def f() do
  # ...
end
```

The former is `f/0`, whereas the latter is `f/1`. Now, as you seem to be familiar with, here's an example of pattern matching:

```
def f(:flag, b) when is_number(b) do
  # paramater 'a' is set as :flag
  # and 'b' is a number, do
  # something with 'b' ...
end

def f(:flag, b) do 
  # paramater 'a' is set as :flag
  # and 'b' is not a number, do
  # something with 'b' ...
end

def f(a, :flag) do 
  # paramater 'a' is not set as :flag
  # but 'b' is,
  # do something with 'a' ...
end

def f(_, _) do
  # otherwise, we don't care
  # what 'a' and 'b' are, maybe
  # do something...
end
```

However, you're right that we could technically perform these checks in the caller function, and call an `f/0`, when appropriate (rather than an `f(a, b)` that does not match any of our initial checks) that we would define separately from `f/2`. But then we might be losing this syntactic convenience and elegance that Elixir offers.

Comment: Thank you for that. That was a very clear explanation :)